# Show image on browser not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, image, browser, show

I need to show the browse image on the same time for this I have used the following code:

```
<script> 
 function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(150)
                                  };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
</script>



<label for="FileID"><img id = "blah" style="width:100px;"src="http://lab.example.com/turn-key-mart/media/<?php echo $customer->getUserImage();?>"></label>

    <input onchange="readURL(this);" style="width:0 !important;" name="file" type="file" id="FileID"/>
```

This it is working fine in Chrome and Mozilla but it is not working in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

See File Reader API Compatibility list here http://caniuse.com/fileapi . It shows the File Reader API does not work in Safari.

So in your code, you have to do something like this,

```
if ( typeof FileReader !== "undefined" ) {
  // preview code here
} else {
 // upload it using some ajax operations and return the file uri from server and set it to the DOM element
}
```

You can try this polyfill to get the feature in Safari.
https://github.com/Jahdrien/FileReader